# highlight selected row and column on mouseover in html table

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a requirement to highlight row and column of the cell in the table on mouseover.The table generated is dynamic which i'm getting the
values from database and displaying in the html table. The structure of the table is exactly as shown below and i cannot modify the existing structure.
Please suggest with my existing html code how can i highlight selected row and column in a table either using jquery/css.
Please find the fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/0w9yo8x6/78/.

Below is the html code:

```
<div>
<table border="1px">
<tr>
<td>
    <table style="width:100%">
        <tr title="Table Header">
        <td>
        Title
        </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>
    <table border="1px">
        <tr>
         <td></td>
         <td bgcolor="grey">Header1</td>
         <td bgcolor="grey">Header2</td>
         <td bgcolor="grey">Header3</td>
         <td bgcolor="grey">Header4</td>
         <td bgcolor="grey">Header5</td>
         </tr>

    <tr>
         <td bgcolor="grey">Row1</td> 
         <td>
            <table>
            <tr>
            <td>
               Cell1  
            </td>
            </tr>
            <tr> 
            <td class='innerCell'>
            Inner cell1
            </td>
            </tr>
          </table> 
      </td> 
         <td>
            <table>
            <tr>
            <td>
               Cell1  
            </td>
            </tr>
            <tr> 
            <td class='innerCell'>
            Inner cell1
            </td>
            </tr>
          </table> 
      </td> 
         <td>
            <table>
            <tr>
            <td>
               Cell1  
            </td>
            </tr>
            <tr> 
            <td class='innerCell'>
            Inner cell1
            </td>
            </tr>
          </table> 
      </td> 
         <td>
            <table>
            <tr>
            <td>
               Cell1  
            </td>
            </tr>
            <tr> 
            <td class='innerCell'>
            Inner cell1
            </td>
            </tr>
          </table> 
      </td> 
         <td>
            <table>
            <tr>
            <td>
               Cell1  
            </td>
            </tr>
            <tr> 
            <td class='innerCell'>
            Inner cell1
            </td>
            </tr>
          </table> 
      </td> 
      </tr>

         <tr>
         <td bgcolor="grey">Row2</td> 
         <td>
            <table>
            <tr>
            <td>
               Cell2  
            </td>
            </tr>
            <tr> 
            <td class='innerCell'>
            Inner cell2
            </td>
            </tr>
          </table> 
      </td> 
         <td>
            <table>
            <tr>
            <td>
               Cell2  
            </td>
            </tr>
            <tr> 
            <td class='innerCell'>
            Inner cell2
            </td>
            </tr>
          </table> 
      </td> 
         <td>
            <table>
            <tr>
            <td>
               Cell2  
            </td>
            </tr>
            <tr> 
            <td class='innerCell'>
            Inner cell2
            </td>
            </tr>
          </table> 
      </td> 
         <td>
            <table>
            <tr>
            <td>
               Cell2  
            </td>
            </tr>
            <tr> 
            <td class='innerCell'>
            Inner cell2
            </td>
            </tr>
          </table> 
      </td> 
         <td>
            <table>
            <tr>
            <td>
               Cell2  
            </td>
            </tr>
            <tr> 
            <td class='innerCell'>
            Inner cell2
            </td>
            </tr>
          </table> 
      </td> 
      </tr>


         <tr>
         <td bgcolor="grey">Row3</td> 
         <td>
            <table>
            <tr>
            <td>
               Cell3  
            </td>
            </tr>
            <tr> 
            <td class='innerCell'>
            Inner cell3
            </td>
            </tr>
          </table> 
      </td> 
         <td>
            <table>
            <tr>
            <td>
               Cell3  
            </td>
            </tr>
            <tr> 
            <td class='innerCell'>
            Inner cell3
            </td>
            </tr>
          </table> 
      </td> 
         <td>
            <table>
            <tr>
            <td>
               Cell3  
            </td>
            </tr>
            <tr> 
            <td class='innerCell'>
            Inner cell3
            </td>
            </tr>
          </table> 
      </td> 
         <td>
            <table>
            <tr>
            <td>
               Cell3  
            </td>
            </tr>
            <tr> 
            <td class='innerCell'>
            Inner cell3
            </td>
            </tr>
          </table> 
      </td> 
         <td>
            <table>
            <tr>
            <td>
               Cell3  
            </td>
            </tr>
            <tr> 
            <td class='innerCell'>
            Inner cell3
            </td>
            </tr>
          </table> 
      </td> 
      </tr>
      </table>
      </td>
      </tr>
      </table>
      </div>
```

Comment: `tr:hover { background-color: ...; }`, perhaps?

Comment: i want to highlight the selected row and column with some color on mouseover. @Biffen

Comment: Can you give us a visual representation of what you are trying to achieve, perhaps an image.

Comment: If you want the whole row and column to be highlighted take a look here: http://css-tricks.com/row-and-column-highlighting/

Comment: @ValentinS. yes this is a good demo , at  http://css-tricks.com/row-and-column-highlighting/

Comment: visual representation is as shown in http://css-tricks.com/examples/RowColumnHighlighting/example-one.php . @cusackBOOM

Comment: @user222 i believe i solved the highlighting row and column issue in my answer

Comment: @ValentinS., "... Let's assume this markup. There are five columns, and so there are five <colgroup>s. Colgroups allow us to style an entire column without needing to manipulate individual table cells ..." so this trick has a caveat. The OP stated he cannot modify the existing structure.. I presume that to mean we won't be manipulating the DOM...

Answer (score 14, accepted):

highlights specific row and column. for the columns i used `nth-child()` as part of the selector. hope this helps.

note: i added class `.myCell` to the tds of the 2nd level nested table for more ease in selector name for jquery.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.myCell').on('mouseover', function() {
        $(this).closest('tr').addClass('highlight');
        $(this).closest('table').find('.myCell:nth-child(' + ($(this).index() + 1) + ')').addClass('highlight');
    });
    $('.myCell').on('mouseout', function() {
        $(this).closest('tr').removeClass('highlight');
        $(this).closest('table').find('.myCell:nth-child(' + ($(this).index() + 1) + ')').removeClass('highlight');
    });
});
```

```css
.highlight {
    background-color:lightgray;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
    <table border="1px">
        <tr>
            <td>
                <table style="width:100%">
                    <tr title="Table Header">
                        <td>
                            Title
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <table border="1px">
                    <tr>
                        <td></td>
                        <td bgcolor="grey">Header1</td>
                        <td bgcolor="grey">Header2</td>
                        <td bgcolor="grey">Header3</td>
                        <td bgcolor="grey">Header4</td>
                        <td bgcolor="grey">Header5</td>
                    </tr>
                    
                    <tr>
                        <td bgcolor="grey" class="myCell">Row1</td> 
                        <td class="myCell">
                            <table>
                                <tr>
                                    <td>
                                        Cell1  
                                    </td>
                                </tr>
                                <tr> 
                                    <td class='innerCell'>
                                        Inner cell1
                                    </td>
                                </tr>
                            </table> 
                        </td> 
                        <td class="myCell">
                            <table>
                                <tr>
                                    <td>
                                        Cell1  
                                    </td>
                                </tr>
                                <tr> 
                                    <td class='innerCell'>
                                        Inner cell1
                                    </td>
                                </tr>
                            </table> 
                        </td> 
                        <td class="myCell">
                            <table>
                                <tr>
                                    <td>
                                        Cell1  
                                    </td>
                                </tr>
                                <tr> 
                                    <td class='innerCell'>
                                        Inner cell1
                                    </td>
                                </tr>
                            </table> 
                        </td> 
                        <td class="myCell">
                            <table>
                                <tr>
                                    <td>
                                        Cell1  
                                    </td>
                                </tr>
                                <tr> 
                                    <td class='innerCell'>
                                        Inner cell1
                                    </td>
                                </tr>
                            </table> 
                        </td> 
                        <td class="myCell">
                            <table>
                                <tr>
                                    <td>
                                        Cell1  
                                    </td>
                                </tr>
                                <tr> 
                                    <td class='innerCell'>
                                        Inner cell1
                                    </td>
                                </tr>
                            </table> 
                        </td> 
                    </tr>
                    
                    <tr>
                        <td bgcolor="grey" class="myCell">Row2</td> 
                        <td class="myCell">
                            <table>
                                <tr>
                                    <td>
                                        Cell2  
                                    </td>
                                </tr>
                                <tr> 
                                    <td class='innerCell'>
                                        Inner cell2
                                    </td>
                                </tr>
                            </table> 
                        </td> 
                        <td class="myCell">
                            <table>
                                <tr>
                                    <td>
                                        Cell2  
                                    </td>
                                </tr>
                                <tr> 
                                    <td class='innerCell'>
                                        Inner cell2
                                    </td>
                                </tr>
                            </table> 
                        </td> 
                        <td class="myCell">
                            <table>
                                <tr>
                                    <td>
                                        Cell2  
                                    </td>
                                </tr>
                                <tr> 
                                    <td class='innerCell'>
                                        Inner cell2
                                    </td>
                                </tr>
                            </table> 
                        </td> 
                        <td class="myCell">
                            <table>
                                <tr>
                                    <td>
                                        Cell2  
                                    </td>
                                </tr>
                                <tr> 
                                    <td class='innerCell'>
                                        Inner cell2
                                    </td>
                                </tr>
                            </table> 
                        </td> 
                        <td class="myCell">
                            <table>
                                <tr>
                                    <td>
                                        Cell2  
                                    </td>
                                </tr>
                                <tr> 
                                    <td class='innerCell'>
                                        Inner cell2
                                    </td>
                                </tr>
                            </table> 
                        </td> 
                    </tr>
                    
                    
                    <tr>
                        <td bgcolor="grey" class="myCell">Row3</td> 
                        <td class="myCell">
                            <table>
                                <tr>
                                    <td>
                                        Cell3  
                                    </td>
                                </tr>
                                <tr> 
                                    <td class='innerCell'>
                                        Inner cell3
                                    </td>
                                </tr>
                            </table> 
                        </td> 
                        <td class="myCell">
                            <table>
                                <tr>
                                    <td>
                                        Cell3  
                                    </td>
                                </tr>
                                <tr> 
                                    <td class='innerCell'>
                                        Inner cell3
                                    </td>
                                </tr>
                            </table> 
                        </td> 
                        <td class="myCell">
                            <table>
                                <tr>
                                    <td>
                                        Cell3  
                                    </td>
                                </tr>
                                <tr> 
                                    <td class='innerCell'>
                                        Inner cell3
                                    </td>
                                </tr>
                            </table> 
                        </td> 
                        <td class="myCell">
                            <table>
                                <tr>
                                    <td>
                                        Cell3  
                                    </td>
                                </tr>
                                <tr> 
                                    <td class='innerCell'>
                                        Inner cell3
                                    </td>
                                </tr>
                            </table> 
                        </td> 
                        <td class="myCell">
                            <table>
                                <tr>
                                    <td>
                                        Cell3  
                                    </td>
                                </tr>
                                <tr> 
                                    <td class='innerCell'>
                                        Inner cell3
                                    </td>
                                </tr>
                            </table> 
                        </td> 
                    </tr>
                </table>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</div>
```

Comment: this is way better than the solution I was putting together.. I'll probably post mine in a bit as an alternative.. but I'm certain this jQuery solution is much faster than the querySelector vanilla solution I'll be adding. here is a comparable performance test: http://jsperf.com/bubblehandlingeventlistener

Comment: @indubitablee , thanks for your support. The same approach as you mentioned in above answer i followed but only the column is highlighting not the row. Please find the jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/0w9yo8x6/85/ . Please suggest what modifications to be done  to highlight row and column.Thanks..

Comment: @user222, you set the css of each row instyle by doing: `style="background-color:rgb(252, 252, 252);"` which overwrites the jquery added class `highlight`. if you remove that from every `<tr>`, it will highlight the row as expected.  see http://jsfiddle.net/0w9yo8x6/86/

Comment: If you use a transparent color like rgba(0, 0, 0, .12) you'll see the current cell even more highlighted.

Answer (score 5):

Since you're nesting tables two deep, your CSS should look something like this:

```
table table tr:hover td {
  background-color: #fbc93d;
}
```

Here's an example based off your fiddle:

## [Example](http://jsfiddle.net/0w9yo8x6/79/)

Comment: I want to highlight selected column also along with row.Please suggest. @Josh Burgess

Comment: @user222, I suspect that'll be a javascript implementation.

Answer (score 0):

try this in your css:

```
td table td:hover{background-color:gray;}
```

Comment: Its only highlighting selected cell, i want to highlight entire row and column of the selected cell on mouseover.. @Ilyas Mimouni

Answer (score 0):

[Example](http://jsfiddle.net/0w9yo8x6/80/)

It is not really great practice putting tables in tables for the sake of it, go check out how to use divs and maybe outline. Also look in to how to create tables using thead, tbody and colgroups.

Hope I could help.

Below is just the HTML code and needs thead and tbody added to it, I'll let you figure that one out.

```
    <table border="1px">
    <colgroup></colgroup>
<colgroup></colgroup>
<colgroup></colgroup>
<colgroup></colgroup>
<colgroup></colgroup>
    <tr>
     <td></td>
     <td bgcolor="grey">Header1</td>
     <td bgcolor="grey">Header2</td>
     <td bgcolor="grey">Header3</td>
     <td bgcolor="grey">Header4</td>
     <td bgcolor="grey">Header5</td>
     </tr>

<tr>
     <td bgcolor="grey">Row1</td> 
     <td>
        <table>
        <tr>
        <td>
           Cell1  
        </td>
        </tr>
        <tr> 
        <td class='innerCell'>
        Inner cell1
        </td>
        </tr>
      </table> 
  </td> 
     <td>
        <table>
        <tr>
        <td>
           Cell1  
        </td>
        </tr>
        <tr> 
        <td class='innerCell'>
        Inner cell1
        </td>
        </tr>
      </table> 
  </td> 
     <td>
        <table>
        <tr>
        <td>
           Cell1  
        </td>
        </tr>
        <tr> 
        <td class='innerCell'>
        Inner cell1
        </td>
        </tr>
      </table> 
  </td> 
     <td>
        <table>
        <tr>
        <td>
           Cell1  
        </td>
        </tr>
        <tr> 
        <td class='innerCell'>
        Inner cell1
        </td>
        </tr>
      </table> 
  </td> 
     <td>
        <table>
        <tr>
        <td>
           Cell1  
        </td>
        </tr>
        <tr> 
        <td class='innerCell'>
        Inner cell1
        </td>
        </tr>
      </table> 
  </td> 
  </tr>

     <tr>
     <td bgcolor="grey">Row2</td> 
     <td>
        <table>
        <tr>
        <td>
           Cell2  
        </td>
        </tr>
        <tr> 
        <td class='innerCell'>
        Inner cell2
        </td>
        </tr>
      </table> 
  </td> 
     <td>
        <table>
        <tr>
        <td>
           Cell2  
        </td>
        </tr>
        <tr> 
        <td class='innerCell'>
        Inner cell2
        </td>
        </tr>
      </table> 
  </td> 
     <td>
        <table>
        <tr>
        <td>
           Cell2  
        </td>
        </tr>
        <tr> 
        <td class='innerCell'>
        Inner cell2
        </td>
        </tr>
      </table> 
  </td> 
     <td>
        <table>
        <tr>
        <td>
           Cell2  
        </td>
        </tr>
        <tr> 
        <td class='innerCell'>
        Inner cell2
        </td>
        </tr>
      </table> 
  </td> 
     <td>
        <table>
        <tr>
        <td>
           Cell2  
        </td>
        </tr>
        <tr> 
        <td class='innerCell'>
        Inner cell2
        </td>
        </tr>
      </table> 
  </td> 
  </tr>


     <tr>
     <td bgcolor="grey">Row3</td> 
     <td>
        <table>
        <tr>
        <td>
           Cell3  
        </td>
        </tr>
        <tr> 
        <td class='innerCell'>
        Inner cell3
        </td>
        </tr>
      </table> 
  </td> 
     <td>
        <table>
        <tr>
        <td>
           Cell3  
        </td>
        </tr>
        <tr> 
        <td class='innerCell'>
        Inner cell3
        </td>
        </tr>
      </table> 
  </td> 
     <td>
        <table>
        <tr>
        <td>
           Cell3  
        </td>
        </tr>
        <tr> 
        <td class='innerCell'>
        Inner cell3
        </td>
        </tr>
      </table> 
  </td> 
     <td>
        <table>
        <tr>
        <td>
           Cell3  
        </td>
        </tr>
        <tr> 
        <td class='innerCell'>
        Inner cell3
        </td>
        </tr>
      </table> 
  </td> 
     <td>
        <table>
        <tr>
        <td>
           Cell3  
        </td>
        </tr>
        <tr> 
        <td class='innerCell'>
        Inner cell3
        </td>
        </tr>
      </table> 
  </td> 
  </tr>
  </table>
```